# Apache Redirect (Proxy) folder to Subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite rule that will take a folder (dynamic) and rewrite it to a subdomain, it also needs to be transparent to the user (proxy).

Here are some examples:

Example 1

```
http://admin.domain.com/a/foo
```

**Should proxy to:**

```
http://a.admin.domain.com/foo
```

Example 2

```
http://admin.domain.com/12345/foo
```

**Should proxy to:**

```
http://12345.admin.domain.com/foo
```

Basically the first folder in the path is being used as the subdomain and the rest of the path is left as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.admin.domain.com/$2  [P,L]
```

If you want to add this to your server config or vhost config, add a "/" in front of the regex so that it looks like this: `^/([^/]+)/(.*)$`.

Comment: The docs say L flag isn't necessary: Use of the [P] flag implies [L] - that is, the request is immediately pushed through the proxy, and any following rules will not be considered.